# Subversion python bindings could not be loaded

Tags: python, windows, svn, mercurial

This is a but of a part 2 in trying to convert an SVN repository to a Mercurial one

command is:

```
hg convert file://c:/svnrepository
```

but, the output I get is:

```
assuming destination svnrepository-hg
initializing destination svnrepository-hg repository
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a CVS checkout
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a Git repo
Subversion python bindings could not be loaded
file://c:/svnrepository is not a local Mercurial repo
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a darcs repo
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a monotone repo
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a GNU Arch repo
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a Bazaar repo
file://c:/svnrepository does not look like a P4 repo
abort: file://c:/svnrepository: missing or unsupported repository
```

The line I'm interested in is:

```
Subversion python bindings could not be loaded
```

I have installed python 2.5, and I have installed the python subversion bindings from the subversion website.  But still getting this error

Comment: You could do a `import svn` from a Python console, to check if that part already works. Make sure you have installed the bindings that correspond to both versions of SVN and Python (I know that sounds obvious).

Comment: I have this same problem on Mac OS.  The purported solution leads to worse errors: `Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
Abort trap`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16950786/14558) for how to install the bindings on Mac OS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem's explained [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) at heading "Converting from Subversion":

> Subversion's Python bindings are a
>   prerequisite. The bindings (generated
>   with SWIG) are installed separately on
>   Windows, and can be found on
>   http://subversion.tigris.org/ . Note
>   that you can't do this with the Win32
>   Mercurial binaries -- there's no way
>   to install the Subversion bindings
>   into its built-in Python library. So
>   you'll need to use a Mercurial
>   installed on top of a stand-alone
>   Python, and you may also need to do
>   something like "set HG=python
>   c:\Python25\Scripts\hg" to override
>   the default Win32 binaries if you have
>   those installed also. For Mac OS X,
>   the easiest way is to install the
>   CollabNet Subversion build, and then
>   copy the content of
>   /opt/subversion/lib/svn-python to the
>   site-package directory of the python
>   installation.

Unfortunately hg + svn + win doesn't apparently get any easier with [hgsubversion](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home), at least judging from [this post](http://intwoplacesatonce.com/2009/07/installing-hg-subversion-on-windows-to-test-it/) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hgsubversion/3bXsI4QkKYg) thereof (I have no Windows installed to try and help out, sigh).

Comment: Oh man that's complicated.  They don't make this easy do they!  I don't even know what "build Mercurial on top of Python" means - I installed them both.

Comment: According to: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2009-May/026015.html the subversion bindings are included in tortoisehg. So you just need to enable the convert extension in tortoisehg.

Comment: Ah ha! Another step forward.  I changed my path to point at hg in TortoiseHG instead of Mercurial and this got over that hurdle.  Now it just doesn't think the repository is an SVN one, ahh!

Comment: Woo! We have lift off.  Would you believe, this doesn't work: "hg convert file://c:/svnrepository" but this does "hg convert file://C:/svnrepository"

Comment: @IP, thanks for the updates -- it's truly amazing that the case (upper vs lower) of the path would make such a difference, but the great thing is that you managed to find that out!!!

Comment: @IP I believe the correct format is "hg convert file:///C:/svnrepository". Note it is 3 forward slashes after file:

Comment: CollabNet does not support OS X Subversion anymore and the latest community installer does not work on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 21):

I just wanted to bring the actual solution out of the comments to Alex Martelli's answer:

> According to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2009-May/026015.html the subversion bindings are included in tortoisehg. So you just need to enable the convert extension in tortoisehg.  – tonfa
>
> Ah ha! Another step forward. I changed my path to point at hg in TortoiseHG instead of Mercurial and this got over that hurdle. Now it just doesn't think the repository is an SVN one, ahh! – Paul

This worked for me as well.

If you're currently using the standard command line version of HG on Windows, the specific steps are:

- Install TortoiseHG
- Right click a file / TortoiseHG / Global Settings... / Extensions / {Check "convert"}
- Make sure TortoiseHG is the path for your hg command:

  - WinKey+Pause / Advanced / Environment Variables / System Variables / Path
  - REMOVE C:\Program Files\Mercurial from the path
  - Make sure C:\Program Files\TortoiseHG is there

Comment: Another way to achieve this seems to be to use the full path to the hg executable.  So in my case this would be "c:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" convert file:///c:/svn/repo_name

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install python-subversion
```

did the trick for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: This made a world of a difference

Comment: question is for windows