# How to install python subversion bindings needed by hg convert on Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: python, macos, svn, mercurial

I am looking for a solution, preferably clean and simple, to enable `hg convert` to work on OS X 10.8 with SVN repositories.

Currently, if you try to convert a SVN repository you will get a `could not load Subversion python bindings` error.

Note: Alex Martelli recommended in another answer to install CollabNet subversion distribution for OS X, still it seems that the latest CollabNet version cannot be installed on OS X 10.8 (the installer locks).

Answer (score 15):

### Using homebrew

The easiest way to get this working is to install `subversion` from source
using [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh) and the `--with-python` flag.

First, make sure you have your command-line tools installed. With Mavericks
and Xcode 5, most commands like `cc` just work even though the command-line
tools aren’t fully installed. If you don’t have a `/usr/include` directory,
then first you need to run

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Once your command-line tools are installed, run:

```
$ brew install subversion --with-python
$ mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
$ echo $(brew --cellar)/subversion/1.8.5/lib/svn-python \
    > ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/svn.pth
```

You can test the bindings by running the unit tests:

```
$ svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.5/subversion/bindings/swig/python/tests
$ cd tests && python run_all.py
```

### Using Apple’s source code

This works for Mountain Lion, but needs tweaks for Mavericks and results in
failing unit tests; see [Simon Wright’s answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348716/14558).

It is
possible to build the subversion bindings for Python using Apple’s version of the subversion source code. The resulting module 
will be exactly compatible and link against all the system libraries. And then `hg convert` will just work.

Here’s how to do it:

1. Download the [subversion tarball](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/subversion/subversion-52.tar.gz) from [opensource.apple.com](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/)
2. Unpack it and configure it:

   ```
   cd subversion-52/subversion && ./configure
   ```
3. In `subversion/bindings/swig/python`, add this Makefile, being sure
    to change leading whitespace to tabs:

   ```
   SHELL = /bin/bash -eu

   CC = gcc -g -O2
   CFLAGS = -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK \
       -I ../proxy \
       -I ../../.. \
       -I ../../../include \
       -I /usr/include/apr-1 \
       -I libsvn_swig_py \
       -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 \

   LDFLAGS = \
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib \
       /usr/lib/libsvn_*-1.0.dylib \
       /usr/lib/libapr-1.dylib \

   .PHONY: build egg test clean install

   test: egg
       mkdir -p tmp && cd tmp \
         && PYTHONPATH=../egg python -S -m svn.tests.run_all

   DESTDIR=$(HOME)/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
   install: egg
           mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}"
       rm -rf "$(DESTDIR)/svn.egg"
       cp -R egg "$(DESTDIR)/svn.egg"
       echo './svn.egg' > "$(DESTDIR)/svn.pth"

   egg: build
       rm -rf egg
       mkdir egg
       cp -R svn egg
       cp -R tests egg/svn
       touch egg/svn/tests/__init__.py
       mkdir egg/libsvn
       cp *.py egg/libsvn
       cp *.so *.dylib egg/libsvn
       # https://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/dynamic_libraries_rpath_and_mac
       for F in egg/libsvn/*.so; do \
         install_name_tool -change libsvn_swig_py.dylib \
           '@loader_path/libsvn_swig_py.dylib' "$$F"; \
       done
       strip -x egg/libsvn/*.so
       touch egg/libsvn/__init__.py
       mkdir -p egg/EGG-INFO
       echo 'Version: 1.6.8' > egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO

   build: libsvn_swig_py.dylib _client.so _core.so _delta.so _diff.so _fs.so _ra.so _repos.so _wc.so

   libsvn_swig_py.dylib:
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -dynamic libsvn_swig_py/swigutil_py.c -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

   _client.so: svn_client.c
   _core.so: core.c
   _delta.so: svn_delta.c
   _diff.so: svn_diff.c
   _fs.so: svn_fs.c
   _repos.so: svn_repos.c
   _wc.so: svn_wc.c

   _%.so: svn_%.c libsvn_swig_py.dylib
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -bundle $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
   _%.so: %.c libsvn_swig_py.dylib
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -bundle $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

   clean:
       rm -rf *.o *.so *.dylib *.dSYM
   ```

   Then run `make` in that directory.
4. If the unit tests passed in the last step, you now have fully-functional
   Python bindings for subversion! Run `make install` if you’re happy, and
   `hg convert` will start working.

---

As is so often the case, it was easier to rewrite the build system from
scratch than to figure out the existing one.

All the scripts from Apple and Subversion really complicate it, but all you really need to do is copy the `.py` files, build a shared library with the common code, and then build each C-language Python module. Figuring out which include files and libraries to use is straightforward: try to build it starting without any includes or libraries, and when the build fails, add a reference to the missing include path or library that is causing the build failure. The tricky part is telling the C-language modules like `_core.so` where to find the dynamic library of common code.

Comment: The `install` target probably needs `-mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)`. Aside from that - great!

Comment: @andrewdotn: you, sir, are a god amongst men.

Comment: @SimonWright Please don’t make massive changes to my answers without talking to me first. If you have a better answer, post your own answer. If you have a question or comment, post a comment. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonWright [Pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/26156) opened so that `brew install subversion --with-python` will soon Just Work™ and [bug reported upstream](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4465) so that it may just Just Work™ in the future.

Comment: Well, your answer (which includes getting Apple’s version of the Subversion code, not using `brew`, whatever that is :) needs a small (*not* massive) change to work on Mavericks.

I don’t have a *better* answer. Yours (with the deleted additions) was just fine.

But I shouldn’t have said “I” where other people would think it was you speaking. Sorry.

Comment: The homebrew instructions here just break my python installation, causing it to crash on startup.

Comment: @IanGilham Can you post an error message? What version of Mac OS are you running, and what version of homebrew are you running as shown by `(cd $(brew --cellar) && git show-ref HEAD)`?

Comment: No error message, I just get the Apple crash dump UI. The `git show-ref` command doesn't work.

Comment: The crash dump UI is an error message, and if you click around you’ll get a stack trace that’ll help you diagnose the crash. And simply saying something “doesn’t work” doesn’t allow anyone else can use to help you solve your problem. What is the output of the command? All I can think of is that if homebrew is installed in a directory with spaces you’ll need to `(cd "$(brew --cellar)" && git show-ref HEAD)` instead. In any case, good luck solving your problem on your own.

Comment: It doesn't help me to keep breaking my environment either. I have more important things to worry about. Running `git show-ref HEAD` in `/usr/local/Cellar` prints nothing and exits with a `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hg from MacPorts, I needed `sudo port install subversion-python27bindings`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an update for Mavericks to [andrewdotn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16950786/40851) above.

Under Mavericks, the only SVN dynamic libraries in `/usr/lib` (the standard place) are, for example, `/usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.0.0.dylib`. This library’s internal names (find using `otool -L`) tell the dynamic loader to look for `libsvn_client-1.0.dylib`. *Normally* this’d also be in `/usr/lib` as a symlink to the real library.

Try this:

1. In andrewdotn's `Makefile`, edit the `LDFLAGS` (second line) to say

   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libsvn_*-1.0.dylib \
2. Set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib

then `make`. I got 2 errors:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_pristine_copy_path (svn.tests.wc.SubversionWorkingCopyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../egg/svn/tests/wc.py", line 192, in test_get_pristine_copy_path
    self.assertEqual(path_to_text_base, wc.get_pristine_copy_path(path_to_file))
  File "../egg/libsvn/wc.py", line 2447, in svn_wc_get_pristine_copy_path
    return apply(_wc.svn_wc_get_pristine_copy_path, args)
SubversionException: ("The node '/var/folders/_q/fvnxz46903z9hjh38fz0lyhm0000gs/T/tmp7vMRZu/foo' was not found.", 155010)

======================================================================
ERROR: test_lock (svn.tests.wc.SubversionWorkingCopyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../egg/svn/tests/wc.py", line 48, in test_lock
    lock = wc.add_lock(self.path, core.svn_lock_create(core.Pool()), self.wc)
  File "../egg/libsvn/wc.py", line 2601, in svn_wc_add_lock
    return apply(_wc.svn_wc_add_lock, args)
SubversionException: ('sqlite: LOCK.lock_token may not be NULL', 200035)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I installed anyway and `hg convert` worked fine.

I suspect you'll need to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as above every time you need to run `hg convert`; hopefully not that often!

Comment: You could add `-rpath /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr` to `LDFLAGS` to avoid needing to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The end of the [dyld(1) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html) documents the `@loader_path`/`@executable_path`/`@rpath` stuff
in unfortunate near-incomprehensibility. But yeah the tests will still fail :/ Installing 1.8.5 from source produces bindings that pass the unit tests, but installing from source is currently a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use hgsubversion with subvertpy instead of hg convert.