# How to convert an SVN repository made by TortoiseSVN under Windows, to Mercurial under Linux?

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisesvn

I have an SVN repository which was created by TortoiseSVN under Windows, I would like to convert it to Mercurial under linux. The repository is a directory on Ubuntu and I have tried to follow instructions from [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension).

I have created a `.hgrc` file in my home directory which has the text;

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

and I get the error:

```
alex@alex-laptop:~/Documents/MATLAB$ hg convert -s --subversion MATLABsvnREPO/
assuming destination MATLABsvnREPO-hg
initializing destination MATLABsvnREPO-hg repository
abort: MATLABsvnREPO/: missing or unsupported repository
```

what steps should be taken?

Comment: There are typos in the command shown above.  Is it the exact command you used?  I would think you want something like `hg convert -s svn MATLABsvnREPO`.

Comment: @TimHenigan,alex@alex-laptop:~/Documents/MATLAB$ hg convert -s svn MATLABsvnREPO/
assuming destination MATLABsvnREPO-hg
initializing destination MATLABsvnREPO-hg repository
Subversion python bindings could not be loaded (try installing the python-subversion package)
abort: MATLABsvnREPO/: missing or unsupported repository

Comment: The part of the output that says "`Subversion python bindings could not be loaded (try installing python-subversion package)`" seems key.  The bindings are listed as a prerequisite in the documentation for the convert extension: (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Subversion)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947039/410975, this helped do it, but from what is produced, I cant upload it to bitcuket

Comment: Why can't you upload it to bitbucket?

Comment: @djc, you can upload an SVN repo to bitbucket? I thought they only did git and Hg

Comment: They do. What did you mean by "this helped do it" (i.e. what's the it that got done)? I presumed that that meant you had a usable Mercurial conversion going.